# How do I instantiate an object when it's constructor expects enumerations?

Tags: java

I have a class that uses enumerable data types.  In it's constructor, it uses two of these.  When I try to instantiate an object of this class from another file, I get an error.
Here is part of the code from the class:

```
public class Card {
public static enum colorType {BLACK, RED};
public static enum suitType {CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE };
public static enum rankType {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT,
        NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING };
private boolean faceup = false;
private rankType rank;
private suitType suit;

//*************************************************************
//Card- constructor.  initializes a card and makes it face down
//*************************************************************
public void Card(rankType r, suitType s){
    this.rank = r;
    this.suit = s;
    this.faceup = false;
}
```

When I try to do this:

```
Card C1 = new Card(ACE,SPADE);
```

from another file, I get an error.  using rankType.ACE and suitType.SPADE as arguments also gives the same error.  I can do Card C1 = new Card(); with no errors, but that would create a card with nothing in it.  The exact error I'm getting is:

```
internal error; cannot instantiate Card.<init> at Card to ()
```

Obviously there is some trick to using enumerables in this situation.  What am I doing wrong?
Fixed.  Solutions to my problems are in posts from uthomas, Tieson T., and the accepted answer.

Comment: "enumerable" != "enumeration". The word "enumerable" is rarely used in Java, but typically it's used to mean something like "iterable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the enum is declared within a class, is a inner type so you must qualify using the outer class:

```
Card C1 = new Card(Card.rankType.ACE, Card.suitType.SPADE);
```

Could be better if you define the enums in separate classes so can be referenced (the type) directly and using static import like `import static RankType.*` you could use:

```
Card C1 = new Card(ACE, SPADE);
```

Also remove  `void` from constructor as stated.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks everyone.  Too bad you can't accept multiple answers on here.  This one contains the solutions to both problems, so it gets that magic check mark.  If there were an invisible check mark, one would go to @uthomas and @Tieson T.

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove the `void` keyword from the Constructor.

Comment: Partial success.  Now there is just the issue of the 'cannot find symbol' errors.  Any ideas there?

Comment: @user663467: Do you keep the Source files in the same package? try to put one of them into an other package and organize the imports.

Comment: Btw.: I totally agree with Tieson T. about the naming convetions :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify where the enum is coming from:

```
Card C1 = new Card(rankType.ACE, suitType.SPADE);
```

Also, your enums should not start with a lower case letter. You should also leave out the "type." So do this:

```
public static enum Color {BLACK, RED};
public static enum Suit {CLUB, DIAMOND, HEART, SPADE };
public static enum Rank {ACE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING };
```

Then the call to the constructor becomes:

```
Card C1 = new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.SPADE);
```

**EDIT:** You also need to remove the void from the constructor, as @uthomas noted. Constructors return the type of object in which they are defined. That is why they have to have the same name as the class itself.

Comment: `Card C1 = new Card(rankType.ACE, suitType.SPADE);` Gives the same error as before, with an additional one.  For both types, I get a 'cannot find symbol' error.  As for the case of the enums, those names were part of the assignment, so I don't want to change them.  Is there something I need to do in order to get Java to know what to do with this class.  In C++ a #include "Card.h"; would be needed.  Is there something like that in java?

Comment: Did you remove the void? Your code works without errors when I create a test project in Eclipse.

Comment: I did have to add a missing curly brace at the end. I assumed you just didn't copy that by mistake. If not, add a curly brace after the constructor and should be GTG.

Comment: The void is gone.  There has to be something with the way I made my testing class.  Since I suck at java, I don't know what's going on.  Right now, my testing class looks like this: `public class TestCards {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card C1 = new Card(rankType.ACE, suitType.SPADE);
    }

}`
That curly brace wasn't there because there is much more to that class after the constructor.

Comment: Make sure you read @Arne Burmeister's comment below. He is 100% correct.

Answer (score 2):

When removed the `void` as *uthomas* wrote, you need to use the correct enums. `rankType` and `suitType` are inner classes of `Card`, so if you want to use them from outside the class, you need to prefix them by the outer class name:

```
Card C1 = new Card(Card.rankType.ACE,Card.suitType.SPADE)
```

As an enum is a class, follow the convention and name it starting with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I bow to the master. I'm used to how our Java prof uses this particular assignment. He makes them use separate files for each enum and each class, so I wrongly assumed they were doing the same. :p